# jQuery UI Tabs -- Can the 'cache' option be applied on a per-tab basis?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm working on a tabbed UI using jQuery UI AJAX tabs.  Some tabs (tabs which are read-only) need to refresh automatically whenever the user leaves and returns to them, while others (tabs which contain forms) should only load once and not refresh when returned to.

Is it possible to specify that a single tab *should* cache it's AJAX contents while others continue to be non-cached?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery UI Tabs caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624228/jquery-ui-tabs-caching)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this question: [JQuery UI Tabs caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624228/jquery-ui-tabs-caching)

The answer was never accepted, but it looks solid and handles pretty much exactly what you're looking for.