# jQuery UI Tabs: How to switch to a (ajax) tab without reloading it?

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

When the caching remains disabled (i.e. `cache: false`), how can I prevent the tab from loading the remote content again? Essentially, I would like to `select` a tab but not `load` it.

Comment: You can't. That's the _point_ of `cache: true`.

Comment: This really is up to the jQ UI Tabs developers to decide how much flexibility they want to this framework to be.

Comment: So what? They didn't give you that flexibility, and it would be non-trivial to implement - but also pointless. This is because the library would have to use the **same** caching behavior as with `cache: true`, because it's not able to know (in advance of the switch) whether or not it will be requested from the server or the cache. At that rate, you **just use `cache: true`** and find a way to load the remote content when you _don't_ want to hit the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that you can control the caching of each tab by setting the 'cache.tabs' data in each tab's anchor element.

I posted the answer in another post: [JQuery UI Tabs caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624228/jquery-ui-tabs-caching/5399579#5399579), but I'll just repost the code here.

```
// disable cache by default
$("#tabs").tabs({
    cache: false,
});
```

Then after the tab content has been loaded for the first time, you can enable the caching for that tab. I simply put it in the `$(document).ready` for the page to be cached:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // cache content for the current tab
    var currentTabIndex = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'selected');
    var currentTabAnchor = $("#tabs").data('tabs').anchors[currentTabIndex];
    $(currentTabAnchor).data('cache.tabs', true)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.tab.data("loaded")) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                ui.ajaxSettings.cache = false,
                ui.panel.html('<img src="images/loader.gif" width="24" height="24" style="vertical-align:middle;"> Loading...'),
                ui.jqXHR.success(function() {
                    ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );
                }),
                ui.jqXHR.error(function () {
                    ui.panel.html(
                    "Couldn't load Data. Plz Reload Page or Try Again Later.");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

...follow a tab's URL instead of loading its content via ajax

Note that opening a tab in a new window is unexpected, e.g. inconsistent behaviour exposing a usablity problem (http://www.useit.com/alertbox/tabs.html).

```
$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
        if( url ) {
            location.href = url;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

By: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...immediately_select_a_just_added_tab