# content retention while switching the tabs in Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have two tabs,  one tab contains a form and grid, the other contains a form. So when first tab loads, the grid gets all the data and loads it. But when I switch to other tab and switch back this loses the grid data and needs to load again, also any edit made are lost tab data itself is not saved.

Is there a way to retain the tab data while switching, so tab only loads once and then retains that data   when it is switched back from a different tab.

I hope I am clear in the question.

Thanks
GMK

```
<script
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
<li><a href="tab1.do?method=load">tab1</a></li>
 <li><a href='tab2.do'>tab2</a></li>
 </ul>
```

This are the basic tabs.

In each of the tabs is there a form and grid, that is too big to post. Now when I switch between the tabs, the each of them need to load the data all over again, instead of retaining the previously loaded data.

How can I avoid that.?

Comment: Can you show some code so that it can be reproduced and fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I actually got the answer from here
[jQuery UI Tabs: How to switch to a (ajax) tab without reloading it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254342/jquery-ui-tabs-how-to-switch-to-a-ajax-tab-without-reloading-it)
The answer by Touhid worked for me.