# jquery ajax tabs question

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Is there anyway to stop the tabs from reloading the content on every access? Everytime I click on a tab, the AJAX request is executed again. Also, when I switch my application tabs,the work I'Ve done on my previous app tab is gone since the tab refreshes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure `cache: true` should work.

Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624228/jquery-ui-tabs-caching) which is very similiar to yours.

There's also a `cookie` parameter you can use to store the `selected tab`.

See the documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

And if none of this works for the oddest of reasons, you can always create your own JavaScript cache object such as a simple `array` and store the tab `id` and `value` in there and pull it every time.  Further, you could serialize this array to `JSON` and store it in a `cookie` that you can check and load on `$(document).ready`...